# ADT list of integers to test program

Tags: java, list, adt

Is there anywhere I can find an ADT list of integers I can use to test this program I wrote for an assignment question? Or can someone tell me how to make one or provide one for me, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
 /**
  * Finds the Max integer from the ADT list of integers
  * 
  * @author (Siren P) 
  * @version (03/12/2016)
  */
  public class MaxIntegers
  {
    public int maxInt (ListReferenceBased aList)
    {
    //Declare variable for max integer
    int max; 

    //Checks every integer in list 
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= aList.size(); i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            //first element stored as max
            max = aList.get(i);
        }
        else
        {
            if(aList.get(i) > max)
            {
                //if element is bigger than current stored element then it will be overwritten
                max = aList.get(i);
            }
        }
    }
    //Returns the max integer
    return max;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArrayList:

```
java.util.List<Integer> aList = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();

// add some ints to the list
aList.add(1);
aList.add(2);
aList.add(3);
aList.add(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

We need the code for the `ListReferenceBase` class to construct a list. My guess would be that it is a sort of `LinkedList`, but I don't know the functions the class offers.

Probably something like that would work (put that in your `MaxIntegers` class)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MaxIntegers test = new MaxIntegers();
    ListReferenceBased testlist = new ListReferenceBased();
    testlist.add(5);
    testlist.add(2);
    testlist.add(55);
    System.out.println(maxInt(testlist));
}
```

Besides that a few side notes:

- You should declare the method `maxInt` as `static`. This means you don't need an object to invoke the method (in this case there is no reason why you would need one, that's why you should make it `static`.)
- Your code likely won't work. If (and this is very likely) `ListReferenceBased` starts the index at 0, then the condition of your for loop (`i <= list.size()`) will go too far. The correct way would be `i < list.size()`.

If there is no implementation of `ListReferenceBased` and it is just a placeholder, you can swap that out in your class and my example with 'LinkedList' for instance. It also would be possible to write `List<Integer>` instead, which would you allow to pass all kinds of lists to the method, they just have to implement the `java.util.List` interface.